# How to test private field is set to supplied value using public method in JUnit?

Tags: java, junit4

I have a class:

```
public class MyEncryptor {

    private StringEncryptor stringEncryptor; // this is an interface ref

    public void setStringEncryptor(StringEncryptor stringEncryptorImpl) {

        if(condition){
            this.stringEncryptor = stringEncryptorImpl;
        }

    }
}
```

When Testing in JUnit for method `setStringEncryptor`, i want to test if instance value `stringEncryptor` is set to what i've supplied in parameter as implementation? or i'm going the wrong way for testing this method?

Below is my failed attempt in a junit test method:

```
MyEncryptor decryptor = new MyEncryptor ();

        StringEncryptor spbe = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
        decryptor.setStringEncryptor(spbe);

        Field f = MyEncryptor .class.getDeclaredField("stringEncryptor");
        f.setAccessible(true);

        Assert.assertSame(f, spbe);
```

I want to test that `stringEnctyptor` is set to spbe in junit

Comment: Why do you want to test the setter? The most important rule to remember, is test the behaviour. For instance, assume that StringEncryptor has a public encrypt() method, your unit test should assert that the encrypt() method encrypts correctly.

Comment: It's not the setter, it has more logic inside, i've just diluted the code to simulate the scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here  you assert that the java.lang.reflect.Field `stringEncryptor` is the same object than the `StringEncryptor` object you create for your test :

```
StringEncryptor spbe = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
...
Field f = MyEncryptor .class.getDeclaredField("stringEncryptor");
f.setAccessible(true);
Assert.assertSame(f, spbe);
```

These are two distinct objects of two distinct and no related classes.
You should first retrieve the value associated to the field :

```
 Object value = f.get(spbe);
```

and then compare the objects :

```
Assert.assertSame(value, spbe);
```

But anyway I don't think it is the good way.
To test a code, the implementation should be testable.
Doing reflection to test the code should be done only if we have really not the choice.
A natural way to test your code is providing a method to get the actual `StringEncryptor` field.

```
public StringEncryptor getStringEncryptor(){
     return stringEncryptor;
}
```

In this way you could assert the field value in a straight way.

Answer (score 1):

The unit test you have given, fails because you attempt to compare a `Field` instance and a `StandardPBEStringEncryptor` instance using `assertSame`. What you should do is: `assertSame(f.get(decryptor), StandardPBEStringEncryptor)`

Notice that we use the `Field::get` method to retrieve the field's value and the argument we give is the instance whose field value we want to retrieve.

However, regardless of that, unit testing a setter type method is redundant and simply adds extra testing code and testing time for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

> i want to test if instance value stringEncryptor is set to what i've
>   supplied in parameter as implementation? or i'm going the wrong way
>   for testing this method?

I think you're going the wrong way. Wherever possible I would test that the unit under test does the encryption as expected, not specifically if a private field is being set. You really want to test the unit functionality, and not the details of its implementation.